# Primitive Root question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Question:

Show that if $m$ is a positive integer and $a$ is an integer relatively prime to $m$ such that $ord_{m}a = m-1$, then $m$ is prime.

So if you could give me guidance and explanations of answers that would be great.

The textbook answer key this question is from does it by a proof by contradiction assuming m is not prime.
But the steps don't really logically follow, so I would appreciate other methods or clear explanation of steps. Thanks.

Comment: This is another form of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test or http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Euler's Theorem, we have $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.

It follows that $a$ has order $\le \varphi(m)$.

We will show that if $m$ is composite, then $\varphi(m)\le m-2$, so $a$ cannot have order $m-1$.

If $m$ is composite, then $m$ has a  factor $d$ with $1\lt d \lt m$. Then $0$ and $d$ are not relatively prime to $m$. So there are at least $2$ integers in the interval $[0,m-1]$ which are not relatively prime to $m$. It follows that $\varphi(m)\le m-2$.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense to me! thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. This is one of the many "counting" arguments in number theory.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If $m$ is composite,  $m=\prod p_i^{r_i}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and integer $r_i>0$

Now $\phi(m)=\prod \phi( p_i^{r_i})=\prod (p_i^{r_i}-p_i^{r_i-1})$ which is clearly  $<m-1$ if $p_i^{r_i-1}>1 \iff r_i>1$ or there are more than one $p_i$s

Comment: Sorry, how exactly does that help answer the question? I understand the other solution above.

And I understand that we can write m in that form if m is composite. But so is it basically just a proof by contradiction then, proving the assumption that m is composite to be wrong?

Comment: @JayC, it shows that $\phi(m)<m-1$ for composite $m$, btw have you noticed my comment in the question?

Comment: Oh I see now.
It was a bit confusing at first. I didn't notice your comment. I see now. Thanks :)